# TCP- IP Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot

Need code for tcp-ip spring boot application. Tried lot of examples. But not getting response from the server.

Tried lot of examples using spring boot but not getting response from server.
Java standalone application working fine. But for TCP IP maven project not reciving response.